# connection between files in node.js JavaScript and html

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, connection, metamask

When I use import in my JavaScript file in node.js it lose the connection with my html file,
and I tried   in my html file but it didn't work

i tried

```
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="JavaScript"></script>
```

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="javascript">

and its work but when I used import in the JavaScript file it didn't
```

Answer (score 1):

Your script and link are invalid.

the `script` connect the HTML to the javascript file so the `src` is the relative path to that particular javascript file.
`<script type="module" src="file.js"></script>`

stylesheet is CSS so the href is the path of the CSS file
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="file.css">`

Comment: thanks for that new information but that's not my problem when i use import in the javascript and run the html file the javascript file don't work

Comment: Are you trying to import one javascript file into another javascript file? If so use `import { module-name } from 'path-to-javascript-file-you-want-to-import.js'` and remember to export the module as well.